# SharePoint Online: Guidance on using "classic" UI libraries in "modern" experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, guidance

Are classic APIs like [SP.UI.Notify.addNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee658473(v=office.14).aspx) supposed to be used in the modern experience of SharePoint Online or are they deprecated? Is there documentation about this anywhere?

`addNotification` adds a notification banner showing a message to the user but the styling and position (lower left corner of the screen) seem odd. So maybe it shouldn't be used anymore?

Answer (score 2):

"Office UI Fabric is the official front-end framework for building experiences in Office 365 and SharePoint." [source](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/guidance/office-ui-fabric-integration) (the source also has instructions on how to use it in SPFx web parts). Perhaps check out the [MessageBar](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/messagebar) component as a replacement for the notification.

Though, I haven't seen any official documentation as to the status of sp.ui.